# Rails backslash unescape post param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, parameters

I have an API endpoint that need to receive some datas by POST request. Those datas are signed, so the signature is actually sent along with it.

The signature is encrypted using a RSA private key and looks like that :

```
viPaFZgLvu8ZGepMbeQS71x8h2+K7gzI9kHk37LqMSO8lBBStcs6AyfghbeR\n2Xg8FBke2RakOo8J0ORFc2LYSK2...
```

When posting the form, this signature change by escaping all the backslash symbol (`\n`) by a double backslash (`\\n`) :

```
viPaFZgLvu8ZGepMbeQS71x8h2+K7gzI9kHk37LqMSO8lBBStcs6AyfghbeR\\n2Xg8FBke2RakOo8J0ORFc2LYSK2...
```

which actually make the process of validating that signature wrong. In order to get rid of if, I've tried using `JSON.parse` which actually output the right signature, but also raise an `Unexpected token` error.

I've also tried using `CGI::unescape` which does not work. From there, I'm stuck figure out how to make this work.

Ideas?

Comment: ... probably not a good idea to post your *actual* RSA private key here... that kind of defeats the purpose of a private key

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The signature is NOT the private key. It is encrypted using the private key and a pass phrase that remain SECRET...

Comment: Good stuff. Just checking. People have posted things like this here before in the past...

Comment: hahaha, thanks for checking

Comment: Is it just this particular character that gives you problems? Can you simply call `gsub("\\n", "\n")` on the signature?

Comment: @eirikir . Thanks a lot. I feel so stupid. It does works. Create a real answer so I can validate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its just this particular character that gives you problems, you can simply `gsub` it:

```
signature = params[:signature].gsub("\\n", "\n")
```